# Is it possible to use SMS notification channel for GCP error reporting?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-error-reporting

I created a SMS notification that works with log based metrics. But I can not find a way to use it for notifications for Error reporting. It does not show when I open the dropdown me nu to select the notification channels for the Error reports [in "Configure notifications" menu](https://console.cloud.google.com/errors).

Am I doing something wrong? Is there anyway to use SMS as notification channel for Error reporting in GCP?

Comment: Just double checking, when you clicked "Configure notifications" then opened "Notifications Channels" dropdown, do you see "Manage notification channels" button?
When you click it, you should see "SMS"

Comment: @WalidGhallab It is weird... I see SMS when I click "Configure notifications". I can create a new SMS notification channel. But it still not appear in dropdown menu after. And when I click again on "Configure notifications", the SMS notification channel disapeared. But when I go check notification channels from log based metrics for example, i still see the SMS notification channel I created.

Comment: @jwtrees may I suggest contacting support to raise your concern about SMS notification channel disappearing when you go to "Configure Notifications" so they can review your project and make a thorough investigation as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching here the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/notifications#create-channel) for creating error reporting channels. As it seems for SMS, it is not showing in the options for error reporting notification channel, however you can maximize the Mobile App for error reporting.